Xcode keeps asking to install actools for building app, tho I already installed it
So I want to test my macOS app so I build it and run it, but asks me to install actool, so I installed it but when I build my app it fails because it was not able to find the tool, and I installed it again and still fails, what I do
Xcode 14.2 in MacBook Air 2017

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
